Unable to Send Email Using App Password (2FA Enabled, IMAP/POP Enabled):
I am trying to send an email using smtplib, an app password, and my gmail account and I'm continuously receiving the following error:










2024-09-24 10:32:55,131
ERROR
Failed to send notification: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials af79cd13be357-7acde53d6c8sm73847185a.44 - gsmtp')



I've tried enabling IMAP and POP like I saw in other stack overflow threads:
Enabled POP/IMAP
I am also using a generated app password.
Here is the code associated:
# notifier.py
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import os
from src.utils.logger import main_logger

class Notifier:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config
        self.smtp_server = config['smtp_server']
        self.smtp_port = config['smtp_port']
        self.sender_email = config['sender_email']
        self.sender_password = os.getenv('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
        self.recipient_email = config['recipient_email']

    def send_notification(self, subject, message):
        try:
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = self.sender_email
            msg['To'] = self.recipient_email
            msg['Subject'] = subject

            msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

            with smtplib.SMTP(self.smtp_server, self.smtp_port) as server:
                server.starttls()
                server.login(self.sender_email, self.sender_password)
                server.send_message(msg)

            main_logger.info(f"Notification sent: {subject}")
        except Exception as e:
            main_logger.error(f"Failed to send notification: {str(e)}")


There is also of course an associated .env and config.yaml file as well.
